# Views Tables on Responsive Layout

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a views table block within a panel.

The table is overflowing the panel and I am trying to understand how to constrain it. I have tried setting it's CSS to various widths but they are always ignored. I can change individual column widths, colours etc but not the width.

Do views tables ignore these settings and just display to the width of their content?
What is the best way to set their width?

Any tips for using views tables in responsive themes(within panels)?

I'm using Drupal 7.23 , [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 7.37 , [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) 7.33 , [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega)-4

**Update:**
In my CSS for this table I have previously tried setting `table {
  width: 100%;` (and with !important). I know it is being applied to the table as when I have very colums it increase the width of the whole table to 100% of it's panel.

The problem occurs when there are a lot of columns and the content text of the column is wide. Then the table overflows past 100%. I can make it thinner by changing font size but I am trying to understand how the views table width is set.

In terms of Views table plugins / modules I am looking at [FooTable](https://www.drupal.org/project/footable) , [Responsive Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables) and (sandbox) [Better Views Tables](https://drupal.org/sandbox/minorOffense/1793630). None of these are mature modules so I am quite nervous about using them.

Comment: Responsive tables is working great for me. Using it now in production in extranet. And the future for it looks good as it is a backport from core Drupal 8.

Comment: There might be lots of things affecting table's width. Can you provide a link that we can see your table and inspect your HTML output?

Answer (score 3):

Set the table width to 100% with css. If some other rule is overriding this, you may have to increase the specificity or add !important.

If you need more control of your table columns, there is a cool module for responsive tables: https://drupal.org/project/responsive_tables. Haven't yet tried it myself.

Comment: thank you for this comment. I have updated the question with your suggestion. Tables containing wide columns often overflow past 100% width.

Comment: Also this might be useful: Why does overflow:hidden not work in a <td>? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) module, with close to 20K reported installs, and an official D7 version, which IMO is pretty 'mature'.

Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides a views plugin for displaying content in a responsive (mobile friendly) grid layout. Rather than trying to force the standard Views grid display to work for mobile this provides the same functionality, but in DIVs instead of tables. Provided is also the ability to specify a horizontal or vertical grid layout which will properly stack the content on a mobile display.
>
> Features:
>
> - Horizontal or vertical grid layouts
> - Custom classes for use with responsive themes

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with the [Responsive Tables Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables_filter) module. It's a mature module with both 7 and 8 versions. It automatically makes Views tables responsive, and also makes tables inserted with a WYSIWYG editor responsive, a huge plus for the site I needed it for. It uses the [Tablesaw](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/tablesaw.html) method for responsive tables.